# How to prevent anchor links from scrolling to a part of a page

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, muse

I am making a Website in Adobe Muse CC 2015 and I have added some anchor links to go to a part of a page however when I click on the link it scrolls to the desired point but what I want is that when I click on the link it should jump to that point instead of scrolling. How can I accomplish this in Muse or in HTML?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can do somehting like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  var link = $('a');
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hash = link.attr("href");
    window.location = hash;
  });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're comfortable getting into the HTML, it's pretty simple with an anchor link. Here's an example:

```
<section id="top"></section>
<a href="#top">Back to the top</a>
```

Do you have a link to the code?

Comment: Good point.There wasn't any code provided so I guess I could make up something?